# how to secure or set a rails style before_filter for all angular controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, angularjs, devise, interceptor

I'm using angularjs for the front end and rails + devise for authentication on the backend.

On the front end I have added a responseInterceptor to redirect to the `/#/sign_in` page upon any 401 response from any xhr request and display a growl style pop-up message using toastr.

```
App.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push('securityInterceptor');
}]);

App.factory('securityInterceptor', ['$injector', '$location', '$cookieStore', function ($injector,$location,$cookieStore) {

  return function(promise) {
    var $http = $injector.get('$http');
      return promise.then(null, function(response){
        if (response.status === 401) {
          $cookieStore.remove('_angular_devise_user');
          toastr.warning('You are logged out');
          $location.path('/#/sign_in');
        }
      });
    };
});
```

My problem is, when I click on a page that loads several xhr requests during the controllers initialization, for example:

```
var products = Product.query();
var categories = Category.query();
var variations = Variation.query();
```

These are needed for various navigation components and they all fire off in parallel, resulting in several duplicate growl-style messages.

Is there a way to make angular quit on the first 401 and stop execution of the rest of the controller from within the interceptor?  In a traditional rails app, there would be a "before_filter" that stops regular execution, preventing the page and queries from loading... what's the best way to do this in angular?

Answer (score 0):

I've been pondering about this problem for my own apps too. A sketch of my thoughts (NOT REAL IMPLEMENTATION, SO BEWARE):

A `userData` service keeps track of whether the user is logged in + other information (e.g. user name, real user name etc):

```
App.service("userData", function() {
    var currentData = {
        loggedIn: false
    };

    function getCurrent() {
        return currentData;
    }

    // called when the user logs in with the user data
    function loggedIn(userData) {
        // the object is REPLACED to avoid race conditions, see explanation below
        currentData = angular.extend({loggedIn: true}, userData);
    }

    return {
        getCurrent: getCurrent,
        loggedIn: loggedIn
    };
});
```

The interceptors keep track of the `currentData`. If an interceptor receives HTTP 401 and the `loggedIn` flag is `true`, it changes the flag to `false` and redirects to the login view. If  an interceptor receives HTTP 401 and the `loggedIn` flag is `false`, it does nothing besides rejecting the request, because another interceptor has done the view redirection.

When the user logs in, the `currentData` is replaced, so as to avoid situations with delayed responses (e.g. call1 and call2 are initiated, call1 responds 401; call2 also results in 401, but the delivery of the actual response is delayed; then the user logs in again; then call2 receives its 401; the second 401 should not overwrite the current state)

```
App.config(["$provide", "$httpProvider", function($provide, $httpProvider) {
    $provide.factory("myHttpInterceptor", ["$q", "userData", "$cookieStore", "toastr", "$location",
        function($q, userData, $cookieStore, toastr, $location) {
            return {
                request: function(config) {
                    config.currentUserData = userData.getCurrent();
                    return config;
                },
                responseError: function(rejection) {
                    if( rejection && rejection.status === 401 && rejection.config && rejection.config.currentUserData && rejection.config.currentUserData.loggedIn ) {
                        rejection.config.currentUserData.loggedIn = false;
                        $cookieStore.remove('_angular_devise_user');
                        toastr.warning('You are logged out');
                        $location.path('/#/sign_in');
                    }
                    return $q.reject(rejection);
                }
            };
        }
    ]);

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push("myHttpInterceptor");
});
```

Also note I am using the newer way to register interceptors, as `$httpProvider.responseInterceptors` seems to be deprecated.